# PhpStorm HTML Code Styling

Tags: intellij-idea, phpstorm

I can not for the life of me find the setting in `Editor/Code Style/HTML` of PhpStorm to change the space from two tabs to a single tab in the highlighted section of the image below.

[image: PhpStorm Screenshot]

Comment: Is it only for HTML? Try looking in the general text edit settings

Comment: Yes. I can't find the section you are referring to.

Comment: It's literally right where you are looking.... Editor > Code Style > HTML.

Comment: Thanks for that, but that as an answer isn't productive!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `Settings | Editor | Code Style | HTML | Tabs and Indents`, set 'Continuation indent' to the value equal to 'Indent'